# Update stop loss based on last entry price

Tags: pine-script

I want to set stop loss order based on price changing for each new entry order. The problem is that stop loss is executed only for the first order. I wrote the code this way:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Mutual funds RSI Index",
 "MF_RSI_IDX",
 default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
 default_qty_value=10,
 initial_capital=1000,
 calc_on_order_fills=true,
 currency=currency.USD,
 commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
 commission_value=0.29,
 process_orders_on_close=true)


if (rsi(close, 14) < 30)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
stopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.80
lastPeak = close * 0.80

sellSignal0 = rsi(close, 14) > 70
sellSignal1 = falling(close, 5)
sellSignal2 = stopLoss >= close
sellSignal3 = lastPeak >= close

strategy.close("buy", when = sellSignal2 or sellSignal3)
plotchar(lastPeak, char="x", location=location.absolute)
plot(strategy.equity)
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Few questions: 1) Are you trying to implement tracking stop-loss? Like if the price goes up - you increase draw the stop-level, closer to the current price? 2) What the exact problem you encounter? You can't exit your position or what? 3) What symbol+resolution for the testing? 4) The variable `sellSignal0` isn't defined. Could you provide minimal _working_ snippet?

Comment: 1) Yes, I'm trying to implement a tracking stop loss. However, I got to know that conditions in strategy.exit function are working simultaneously, not as alternatives (so it's not like in my statement either "stop" or "when" conditions are met).
2) The order is executed twice, and the second entry is never closed.
3) ONCY (Oncolytics Biotech); 1 day resolution.
4) sellSignal0 = rsi(close, 14) > 70

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that I am trying to implement tracking stop loss estimated in percentage of latest high, not based on ticks.

Comment: what are the params in the `strategy()` function?

Comment: `The order is executed twice, and the second entry is never closed` entry order or exit? Could you post minimal _working_ script which could be applied to the chart and I could see the problem?

Comment: I updated the question and posted the full strategy script. It changed a bit because I was working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
strategy("Mutual funds RSI Index",
 "MF_RSI_IDX",
 overlay=true,
 default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
 default_qty_value=10,
 initial_capital=1000,
 currency=currency.USD,
 commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
 commission_value=0.29)


strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, when=rsi(close, 14) < 30)

stopLoss = 0.0
if strategy.position_avg_price != 0
    stopLoss := max(strategy.position_avg_price * 0.9, nz(stopLoss[1]))

limitPrice = float(na)
// force exit
if rsi(close, 14) > 70
    limitPrice := 0.0

strategy.exit("buy", stop=stopLoss, limit=limitPrice)
```

Is that what you are looking for? I think it's better to close the position by `exit` here and note, that I removed `calc_on_order_fills` and `process_orders_on_close`, because they are pretty controversial.

Comment: What nz() does in this case? Does it change offset series into a single value?

Comment: And why do you think `that calc_on_order_fills` and `process_orders_on_close` are controversial?

Comment: I changed the stopLoss calculation a bit:  `stopLoss := max(strategy.position_avg_price * 0.9, nz(close[1]))` . This way stopLoss is raised every time the market goes up.

Comment: `nz()` returns 0 for the very first bar in the history (because the value of `stopLoss` befor the first bar was `na`). It lets to `max` choose maximum of current position and 0. 
I think the it's better to set `stopLoss` back to zero, because otherwise previous stop can affect exit. NOTE: I've changed my code to fit this condition.

Comment: `calc_on_order_fills` can provoke peek into the future because its implementation. There's an article with describing this case is comming, but I don't know when it's published. Hope very soon. `process_orders_on_close` fills an order current pirce (already happened trade), but in reality, you can't buy at price of last trade - probably, the next price will different, so using `process_orders_on_close` affects strategy's accuracy.